# Paypal Client Website Payment Options

Tags: paypal

Currently we are using Paypal's REST API to setup a paypal payment process on our client's website.

Our webcontrol sits inside an iframe on their website and it is from this control the the paypal process is started and processed. Currently that works ok.

The issue we have is that this requires each customer of ours to have a business account (which is required any way we go so that bit is ok) but they then need to go the developer portal on their account and setup a an App ClientID and Secret (which is the bit we are hoping to do without to make it as simple as possible for our customers).

I have noticed solutions like wix.com offer paypal integration to their customers and only require the email address of their customer's paypal account and they handle the rest of the setup from there automatically.

I am just looking for some guidance on which product in Paypal's range should I be looking at to implement the same sort of solution setup for our customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct: the REST API service does not (currently) support placing API Calls for other users.

Alternatives:

1. Classic API: You can call the API in the name of a customer (who first needs to grant your API user access to his account) by passing the "SUBJECT=E-Mail Address" Variable. Usually used in conjunction with Express Checkout - see: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/

   If you want to go this route, you may want to look into the permission service API under https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/permissions/ - it allows you to programmatically request the required permissions from a seller.
2. Adaptive Payments: 
   Often used by market places, we're dealing with 3 parties within Adaptive Payments:

   a. API Caller --> The API caller placing the API calls and receiving all infos
   b. The sender --> The person sending money to one or more recipients
   c. The receiver(s) --> One or more receivers of the payment. As Adaptive Payments is pretty much using PayPals "Send Money" functionality, no further permissions need to be requested from the receivers.

   See: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/
3. Website Payments Standard: Just add a different e-mail address to the "business" variable and you're done.

   See: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/

Comment: By using this can i use INR as base currency